# Conversion from string "I" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox, command

I am getting this error when I insert several `TextBox` commands.

> Conversion from string "I" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

The code for which I am getting this error is:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "I" Then TextBox20.Text = "I" And TextBox32.Text = "I" And TextBox44.Text = "I"
If TextBox2.Text = "I" Then TextBox19.Text = "I" And TextBox31.Text = "I" & TextBox43.Text = "I"
If TextBox3.Text = "I" Then TextBox17.Text = "I" And TextBox29.Text = "I" & TextBox42.Text = "I"
If TextBox4.Text = "I" Then TextBox18.Text = "I" And TextBox28.Text = "I" & TextBox41.Text = "I"
If TextBox8.Text = "I" Then TextBox16.Text = "I" And TextBox27.Text = "I" & TextBox40.Text = "I"
If TextBox7.Text = "I" Then TextBox15.Text = "I" And TextBox26.Text = "I" & TextBox39.Text = "I"
If TextBox6.Text = "I" Then TextBox14.Text = "I" And TextBox25.Text = "I" & TextBox38.Text = "I"
If TextBox5.Text = "I" Then TextBox13.Text = "I" And TextBox24.Text = "I" & TextBox37.Text = "I"
If TextBox30.Text = "I" Then TextBox11.Text = "I" And TextBox23.Text = "I"
If TextBox33.Text = "I" Then TextBox10.Text = "I" And TextBox22.Text = "I" & TextBox35.Text = "I"
If TextBox48.Text = "I" Then TextBox47.Text = "I" And TextBox21.Text = "I" & TextBox34.Text = "I"
If TextBox52.Text = "I" Then TextBox51.Text = "I" And TextBox46.Text = "I" & TextBox45.Text = "I"
If TextBox9.Text = "I" Then TextBox12.Text = "I" And TextBox50.Text = "I" & TextBox49.Text = "I"
```

Any suggestions? They all begin with `If TextBox` not just `TextBox`

Comment: It is remarkable how you suddenly switched from And to & and can't see that.

Comment: You really need to come up with a better naming convention for your textboxes. (and a better way to handle repetitive code like the above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix just one line as an example for the other lines.

```
If TextBox1.Text = "I" Then 
      TextBox20.Text = "I" 
      TextBox32.Text = "I" 
      TextBox44.Text = "I" 
End If
```

The [AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx) is used to execute a logical operation between two expression that result in a boolean TRUE/FALSE result not to repeat the execution of a command.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I will mark your answer correct in 7 minutes (That's when I can accept it, don't really know why?) The first one worked, I will try the rest. Thank You!!

Comment: While you wait the 7 minutes delay you could entertain yourself with [Fastest gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: I suppose, Thank you again.